# Android Graphical Layout error

Tags: android, graphical-layout-editor

For some reason i don't know graphical layout on eclipse stop working

After some test i know the probleme is the EditText

I don't know why i paste here my EditText tell me if i do something wrong

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10" android:inputType="">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Eclipse error log is:

```
String index out of range: 0
```

Comment: android:inputType="" ???????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add android:inputType="" to some type which you want like "text".It will work fine.

Comment: Thx in the sample i have they don't set it and it's work but maybe they don't use graphical layout

This work perfectly now i accept your answer in 5 minute because now stack overflow don't allow me.

Sorry for the dumb question i was thinking it's a strangest bug ...

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10" android:inputType="PLS FILL ME">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

You should either remove `android:inputType=""` or fill it with some valid value

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to remvoe the `inputType` from your edit text or you have to enter some value in this field :

**Put some value :**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

**Or remove the tag**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```